# Working with Queue<T> in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# class that has 3 private members, two of type `Queue<uint>` and one of `Queue<int>`.  I am trying to create a single funtion that I can pass the queues into that will trim their length to a specific value however I have not be able to get anything to compile.  I have tried the following

```
private Queue<uint> a;
private Queue<int> b;

...
this.trimQueue(a);
this.trimQueue(b);
...
private void trimQueue(Queue<t> tempqueue)
{
     while (tempqueue.Count > _MAX_VALUES)
     {
          tempqueue.Dequeue();
     }
}
```

I have also tried the following with no luck.

```
private void trimQueue<t>(t tempqueue) where t : Queue<t>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Update:  It seems like the correct answer was

```
private void trimQueue<T>(Queue<T> tempqueue)
```

but that response got deleted :(

Comment: Google "c# how to write a generic method", take the first hit.

Comment: What is the compilation error message?

Comment: @HansPassant.  I took the first link with the google search you recommended but it really didn't answer the question.  Do you have the specific link google pointed you too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `Queue<int>` and `Queue<uint>` are treated as different types.

Therefore you have to make the `trimQueue` method also generic:

```
private void trimQueue<T>(Queue<T> tempqueue)
{
     while (tempqueue.Count > _MAX_VALUES)
     {
         tempqueue.Dequeue();
     }
}
```

Call it using the type:

```
this.trimQueue<uint>(a);
this.trimQueue<int>(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `private void TrimQueue<T>(Queue<T> queue)`
also to restrict the T you can also add `where T : struct`

Comment: It would be pointless to add a constraint on `T` because there's nothing in the method that relies on anything specific about `T`.  Even if it's not required, why prevent someone trimming a queue of reference types?